# Render 2 or more columns using map in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how can i render 2 columns using map in react ? thats my data:

```
super();
        this.state = {
            todos: [
                { id: 1, title: '1My ', about: 'lorem ipsum...', skills: 'react' },
                { id: 2, title: '2My', about: 'lorem ipsum...', skills: 'react' },
                { id: 3, title: '3My', about: 'lorem ipsum...', skills: 'react' },
                { id: 4, title: '4My', about: 'lorem ipsum...', skills: 'react' },
                { id: 5, title: '5My', about: 'lorem ipsum...', skills: 'react' },
                { id: 6, title: '6My', about: 'lorem ipsum...', skills: 'react' },

            ],
            currentPage: 1,
            todosPerPage: 1
        };
```

id like to learn the logic and put the array in 2 ou more columns, my output:

```
const renderTodos = currentTodos.map((todo, index) => {
            return <div className="container">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col">
                        <div class="card" >
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 key={index} class="card-title text-danger">{todo.title}</h5>
                                <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"></h6>
                                <p class="card-text text-danger">{todo.about}</p>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">{todo.skill}</a>
                                <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>;
        });
```

Comment: Can you share your full component, that's not so clear

Comment: simply map the col instead to full row, you can achieve your goal easily